# How to define an indentation command?

Tags: indentation

I'm confused in how I might go about writing a command to create an indention in LaTeX.

For example, I am making an outline, and I want the Main Points to have an `\hspace` of `30pt`. How do I create a command (`\main`) that will allow me to do that consistently throughout my document?

I am trying to learn LaTeX, but even this simple task is eluding me.

```
\newcommand{\main}          %% I know this is wrong
{
     \hspace{30pt}
}
```

Comment: The first row of each paragraph has been indented by default. If you need to change the indentation space, modify the existing indentation space definition at the preamble. The change will be reflected throughout the document automatically.

Answer (score 6):

If you need that your paragraph introduced by `\main` is exactly 30pt from the left margin, you can define

```
\newcommand{\main}{\par\noindent\hspace*{30pt}\ignorespaces}
```

With `\par` you are sure to start a new paragraph, with `\noindent` you disable the automatic indentation, with `\hspace*{30pt}` you insert the desired spacing. I've added `\ignorespaces` though it's not necessary here because if you try a different definition, for instance by adding a title in bold face, with

```
\newcommand{\main}[1]{\par\noindent\hspace*{30pt}%
  \textbf{#1}\enspace\ignorespaces}
```

you don't incur in the spurious space that would be introduced by an input such as

```
\main{Item} text
```

without `\ignorespaces`.

You should consider, however, a list environment, for your outline. For example

```
\newenvironment{outline}
  {\begin{list}{}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{30pt}}}
  {\end{list}}
```

and input your items as

```
 \begin{outline}
 \item First element
 \item Second element
 ...
 \end{outline}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the built in `\indent` if you want to indent individual paragraphs.
If you want LaTeX to automatically indent the start of all starting paragraphs, you can use the `indentfirst` package to indent the first paragraph. And if you want to change the indentation length you can use `\setlength{\parindent}{0.25in}`